# Closure: change ENABLE_DEBUG_LOADER before base.js is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Is it possible to set the `ENABLE_DEBUG_LOADER` to `false` before Closure's `base.js` is loaded to prevent `base.js` from attempting to load `deps.js`?

I want this because I'd like to build a source distribution which is just the result of running `cat $(depswriter.py ...)` (because I want a single-file distribution, but I don't want to compress/optimize it because that will make debugging difficult).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set CLOSURE_NO_DEPS to true, aka: `var CLOSURE_NO_DEPS = true;`

Had to deal with this for Rails sprocket plugin: https://github.com/igrigorik/closure-sprockets/commit/6a13edf63e7b1cf9098c6c87e96576e064d09251

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I want. Thanks, Ilya.